# Proguard Issue : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query"

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, proguard

I have used AWS services and used dynemo db in my application.

I am using following 3 Services of AWS.

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.15'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.15'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.6.15'
```

Everything works fine and project successfully builds too.

Now I have enabled proguard in my project and added following rules in proguard.pro file.

```
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keepnames class com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazonaws.services..Handler
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.*
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.metrics.**
```

But I am getting following error when i try to request for query using DynamoDBQueryExpression
**Error :** `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query".`

Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many efforts i found the solution for it. There was some issue of conflict, i have added following rules for **Realm** in **proguard-rules.pro** file

```
# Realm
-dontnote io.realm.internal.SyncObjectServerFacade
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class * { *; }
-keep class io.realm.internal.KeepMember
-keep @io.realm.internal.KeepMember class * { @io.realm.internal.KeepMember 
*; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
-keep class io.realm.RealmCollection
-keep class io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection
-keepclasseswithmembernames class io.realm.** {
  *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line too on ProGuard file

```
-keep public class com.amazonaws.** { *;}
```

it will not minify whole classes of `com.amazonaws`, package, by this your problem will be resolved if its real problem of Pro-guard.

Comment: i have tried but not worked for me. Is there any other solution?